# Page migrated error in Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

In my Facebook application, when I query info about a Facebook page through the open graph API, I regularily see errors like `(#21) Page ID 290260024371666 was migrated to page ID 122581454447308.  Please update your API calls to the new ID` when querying the open graph API.

What is this migration? How do pages migrate to another? Is that something that can happen anytime?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=213602951994043

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. This error is about a page (not a profile) migrated to another page.

Answer (score 2):

Can happen anytime when user merge his fanpage with a other page of similar name. 
Happens also for Places movie and many other object. 
Would be nice if the Graph Api would return a extra field with new PageID .